# How do I instruct ArrayAdapter to redraw all its elements?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have list of items in a (subclass of) ArrayAdapter, and when one of the items in the ArrayAdapter is changed, they all need to update their view. (For some context, its a bulk pricing model, where the more things you buy, the cheaper everything else gets, and I want to update the price of everything when you add something to your cart)

From reading the documentation, I expected [notifyDataSetChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) to do the trick, but it isn't doing what I want. What should I be doing?

As requested, here is my getView function. The totalPrice() method of orderChoice is the one that changes depending on what else is selected.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent){
    final EditingOrderChoiceAdapter adapter = this;
    View choiceView = convertView;
    if (choiceView == null){
        LayoutInflater choiceViewInflater = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        choiceView = choiceViewInflater.inflate(R.layout.order_choice_row, null);
    }

    final OrderChoice orderChoice = choices.get(position);
    if (orderChoice != null){
        TextView choiceName = (TextView)choiceView.findViewById(R.id.choice_name);
        choiceName.setText(orderChoice.choice.name);

        TextView choicePrice = (TextView)choiceView.findViewById(R.id.choice_price);
        choicePrice.setText(orderChoice.totalPrice().formatted());

        CheckBox choiceCheckBox = (CheckBox)choiceView.findViewById(R.id.choice_checked);
        choiceCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                orderChoice.selected = isChecked;
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        choiceCheckBox.setChecked(orderChoice.selected);
    }
    return choiceView;
}
```

Comment: Are you modifying the data on which your adapter is based(`ArrayList`, `array` , `cursor`)? Maybe you should post the `getView` method of your custom adapter.

Comment: I posted the getView() method.  I'm not modifying the data, but the return values of some of the methods on the data is changing.

Comment: Are you sure your data changes after checking a item in the list?

Comment: Yes. When I scroll down and scoll up again, the views are reloaded, and they display the new value.

Answer (score 0):

Are you recreating the collection or are you updating items in the collection? If you recreate the collection, notifyDataSetChanged() won't work. In case items are being updated, it should work.

If you really need to destroy/recreate the collecion, then set a new adapter to the list.

Comment: I'm not changing the data in the items, but since the return value of a method in the items depends on values in the other items, the text that should be displayed is different.